# What is the potential to use for non-dispersion interactions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, dipole

Although liquid argon’s intermolecular potential can be described using a Lennard-Jones (LJ) potential, which takes into account dispersion forces (induced dipole-induced dipole interactions), what potential do you use when also including the effects of dipole-induced dipole and dipole-dipole interactions?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/why-are-c6-dispersion-forces-named-c6

Answer (score 2):

Because all three of these interactions are of the same order in the interelectronic distance ($1/r^{6}$), they are *all* captured within the [Lennard-Jones potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) to the extent of the accuracy of the potential. From the "Limits" section:

The term [Van der Waals (vdW) forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) roughly includes the following [intermolecular forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermolecular_force):

> - the permanent dipole-permanent dipole force ([Keesom force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keesom_force)), which is an electrostatic term,
> - the permanent dipole-induced dipole force ([Debye force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_force)), which is an induction or polarization term,
> - the induced dipole-induced dipole force ([London dispersion force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_dispersion_force)), which is the dispersion term.

the forms of which are

$$
\begin{align}
V_{\text{Keesom}} &= \frac{-m_{1}^{2}m_{2}^{2}}{24\pi^{2}\epsilon_{0}^{2}\epsilon_{r}^{2}k_{b}Tr^{6}} \\
V_{\text{Debye}} &= \frac{-m_{1}^{2}\alpha_{2}}{16\pi^{2}\epsilon_{0}^{2}\epsilon_{r}^{2}r^{6}} \\
V_{\text{LJ}} &= 4\epsilon \left[ \left( \frac{\sigma}{r} \right)^{12} - \left( \frac{\sigma}{r} \right)^{6} \right] 
\end{align}
$$

Note that the LJ potential contains both a repulsive ($1/r^{12}$) and attractive ($-1/r^{6}$) component. This is not *the* form of the dispersion interaction, but is both a suitable mathematical form that encapsulates a few noncovalent (vdW) interactions together and is easy to evaluate on a computer.

You may also be interested in the form of a more complicated potential, such as the [AMOEBA polarizable force field](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jp910674d), which uses a slightly different form for the pairwise vdW interaction ($i,j$ are atoms)

$$
\begin{align}
U_{\text{vdw}}(ij) &= \epsilon_{ij} \left( \frac{1.07}{\rho_{ij} + 0.07} \right)^{7} \left( \frac{1.12}{\rho_{ij}^{7} + 0.12} - 2 \right) \\
\rho_{ij} &= \frac{R_{ij}}{R_{ij}^{0}} \\
\epsilon_{ij} &= \frac{4\epsilon_{ii}\epsilon_{jj}}{(\epsilon_{ii}^{1/2}+\epsilon_{jj}^{1/2})^{2}} \\
R_{ij}^{0} &= \frac{ (R_{ii}^{0})^{3} + (R_{jj}^{0})^{3} }{ (R_{ii}^{0})^{2} + (R_{jj}^{0})^{2} }
\end{align}
$$

and also considers up to permanent and induced quadrupole moments

$$
\begin{align}
U_{\text{elec}}^{\text{perm}}(r_{ij}) &= M_{i}^{T} T_{ij} M_{j} \\
T_{ij} &= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z_j} & \mathrm{L} \\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial y_j} & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial z_j} & \mathrm{L} \\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y_i \partial x_j} & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y_i \partial y_j} & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y_i \partial z_j} & \mathrm{L} \\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j} & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z_i \partial x_j} & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z_i \partial y_j} & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z_i \partial z_j} & \mathrm{L} \\ 
\mathrm{M} & \mathrm{M} & \mathrm{M} & \mathrm{M} & \mathrm{O}
\end{bmatrix} \left( \frac{1}{r_{ji}} \right)
\end{align}
$$

along with the other typical bonded terms found in modern force fields.

[Here](https://janheyda.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/electrostatics-multipoles.pdf) is a nice set of notes that describes the interaction between electric multipoles to different orders.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the potentials for Keesom force and Debye force here are all averaged for ALL angles. The exact dependence on the inter electronic distance w/o being averaged are here: http://www.chem1.com/acad/webtext/states/interact.html